# Clear() method on GWT Widgets doesn't remove the child Widgets' ClickHandler

Tags: gwt

I suspect an issue regarding a Widget's ClickHandler. Is it the case that removing a ClickHandler-added-Widget from its parent by calling clear() method of the parent Widget results in live ClickHandler?

Answer (score 0):

You are right with the assumption that the ClickHandler of an element is not removed when the element itself is removed from its parent. But this is not an issue because the `clear()` method of the parent just removes all child widgets, nothing more. Otherwise you would always have to add the ClickHandler again if you remove the element from its parent and add it to a new container for example.

You can use a HandlerRegistration to remove the ClickHandler after calling the `clear()` method if this is really needed in your case.

```
HandlerRegistration handler = button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        //Do something
    }
});

parent.clear();
handler.removeHandler();
```

If you want to do this for all child widgets you could use a list with HandlerRegistrations (you have to keep up to date always you're adding or removing a widget) and loop through this list calling `removeHandler()` when clearing the parent.

Comment: clear() also kills the EventHandlers on those widget added to Panel. So, we don't need to take care of it. http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dom_events_memory_leaks_and_you.html